# Material UI - Text goes outside the Container/Box?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have an `Alert` where it displays long strings.
Here is my code:

```
<Container maxWidth="md">    
<Box sx={{ mt: 3, border:1}}>
    <Box>
        {hasSubmitted ?
            <div>
                <Alert sx={{mt:3}} severity="success">
                {receivedData}
                </Alert>
            </div>
        : null}
    </Box>
</Box>
</Container>
```

However it then shows up like this:
[image: Text goes out]

Very new to Material UI. How can I fix this? Thank you!

## Update

I used this instead:

```
<Typography
     variant="body2"
     align="center"
     style={{ wordWrap: "break-word"}}
     sx={{mt:3}}
>
      {receivedData}
</Typography>
```

It works but it's not an `Alert` now. I think the problem is on the `Alert` component. Still if anyone has any solutions, I'm still open for them. Thank you!

Comment: There is no space in your line. So break word won't work. Use word-break: break-all; to fix your issue

Answer (score 2):

try using the `break word` css property. [Read more here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp)

```
<Container maxWidth="md">    
<Box sx={{ mt: 3, border:1}}>
    <Box style={{width:'100%}}>
        {hasSubmitted ?
            <div style={{width:'100%}}>
                <Alert sx={{mt:3}} severity="success" style={{wordWrap:'break-word', width:'100%}}>
                {receivedData}
                </Alert>
            </div>
        : null}
    </Box>
</Box>
</Container>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the response. I tried the `break word` but it still didn't work. The text still goes outside the box/container. I really don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: @DC37 try my answer now, I've made some changes

Comment: Thank you. The alert box (green background) now also goes out of the borders, however the text now stays inside the alert. I think we're getting there.

Comment: But when I turn responsive mode (chrome) the text still goes out

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to use `style` prop, in order to customize the component `Alert` use global class name or styleOverrides property, in your example I used global class name:

```
.MuiAlert-message {
 min-width: 0;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Check this: https://mui.com/api/alert/#css

Answer (score 1):

Hi friend try to use this props:

```
<container sx={{
                    maxWidth: ? ,
                    maxHeight: '100%',
                    width: '100%',
                    wordWrap: 'break-word',
                    textAlign: ?,
                    p:?,   }}>
```